# How to set a List of objects to another List of objects

Tags: java, list

**Scenario**
I've two DTO classes of the same name (CobrandedCardDto) having same attributes but in different packages.

Packages are:

```
 1. com.loyalty.marketplace.offers.member.management.outbound.dto
 2. com.loyalty.marketplace.outbound.dto
```

The attributes in CobrandedCardDto are:

```
 private String partnerCode;
 private String bankId;
 private String status;
 private String cardType;
```

I've `List<CobrandedCardDto>` coming up from a service in Package (`com.loyalty.marketplace.outbound`) which I need to set to `List<CobrandedCardDto>` in Package (`com.loyalty.marketplace.offers.member.management.outbound`)

Basically I want to do something like this;

```
memberDetails.setCobrandedCardDetails(MemberAccountInfoDto.getCobrandedCardDetails());
```

where `cobrandedCardDetails` is variable for `List<CobrandedCardDto>`

**Question**
I'm unable to set the list. I'm facing this error. How could I resolve this issue?

> The method
> setCobrandedCardDetails(java.util.List<com.loyalty.marketplace.offers.member.management.outbound.dto.CobrandedCardDto>)
> in the type GetMemberResponse is not applicable for the arguments
> (java.util.List<com.loyalty.marketplace.outbound.dto.CobrandedCardDto>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to map from one type to the other. One simple solution would be to manually stream them and map the, like this:

```
List<com.loyalty.marketplace.outbound.dto.CobrandedCardDto> dtos = ...;
List<com.loyalty.marketplace.offers.member.management.outbound.CobrandedCardDto> mappedDtos = dtos.stream()
    .map(dto -> new com.loyalty.marketplace.offers.member.management.outbound.CobrandedCardDto(
       dto.getPartnerCode(),
       dto.getBankId(),
       dto.getStatus(),
       dto.getCardType()
    ))
    .toList();
```

If will be doing this with other objects as well, you can consider using a mapping library such as mapstruct: https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct

PS: consider renaming one of them so that you don't need the fully qualified name.

Update: if you don't want to add the @AllArgsConstructor, you can see the setters instead:

```
.map(dto -> {
    var mappedDto = new com.loyalty.marketplace.offers.member.management.outbound.CobrandedCardDto();
    mappedDto.setPartnerCode(dto.getPartnerCode());
    mappedDto.setBankId(dto.getBankId());
    mappedDto.setStatus(dto.getStatus());
    mappedDto.setCardType(dto.getCardType());    
    return mappedDto;
}).toList();
```

Though, in my opinion, the all args constructor solution looks better.

Comment: I've tried your method, the only challenge is that It requires parameterized constructor in CobrandedCardDto class and I already have @NoArgsConstructor on my class. any workround?

Comment: @AyubJamal yes, you can use the setters, I have updated my answer and added this option. though it might be better to add the `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Since this method is kind of a Mapper method that shall be used across different classes, it is necessary to put it as a static mapper method in a Mapper class.

So let's say you have the following Mapper class:

**CobrandedCardMapper**:

```
public static List<com.loyalty.marketplace.offers.member.management.outbound.CobrandedCardMapper> getMappedListOfCobrandedCard(List<CobrandedCardMapper> list){
return list.stream()
.map(cobrandedCardMapper ->{
com.loyalty.marketplace.offers.member.management.outbound.CobrandedCardMapper cobrandedCardMapperDTO = new com.loyalty.marketplace.offers.member.management.outbound.CobrandedCardMapper();
//Then use Apache Commons  Bean Utils copy properties function based on field name
BeanUtils.copyProperty(cobrandedCardMapperDTO,cobrandedCardMapper);
return cobrandedCardMapperDTO;
).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Then you can call the method in your set, to get the converted list